# found user with username + discriminator

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to find a user using the discriminator together
e.g.: Banana#3591
but when I try to search it that way it doesn't find

```
let member =
message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.username.startsWith(args.slice(0).join(" ")) + member.user.discriminator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your username will simply show your username, not your discriminator.
Try this:

```
let stuff = args[0];
stuff = stuff.split("#");
let member = message.guild.members.cache.find(userr => userr.user.username == stuff[0] && userr.user.discriminator == stuff[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get username and discriminator, use `<user>.tag`.

```js
const user = message.author
const tag = user.tag //returns User#0000
```